# Is there a public repository/api of coin/token logos

Tags: api, bitcoin-logo

I am developing an cryptocoins related app and I would like to display cryptocoin logos there for all coins available for trade. Is there an API out just a publicly accessible repository that would give me those logos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking for the same thing and I found - https://www.cryptocompare.com/api

Comment: That URL has changed, can you point to the current URL of the logos API?

Answer (score 2):

All cryptocurrency logos from Coinmarketcap.com and two solutions how to fetch them: https://github.com/dziungles/cryptocurrency-logos

Answer (score 1):

My reply from another thread :

I just found Crypto Icons API : https://cryptoicons.org/

It is customizable and easy to use. Free also.